# Can I run two different dual lands that produce the same colors of mana?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-manabase

I have [Thornwood Falls](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Thornwood%20Falls) and [Simic Guildgate](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Simic%20Guildgate).

Am I allowed to run four of each of these cards in one deck?

I cannot find a ruling on this, maybe my google-fu is a bit off though...

Comment: As explained at the linked duplicate, all that matters is the *name* of the card, not the effect. (Also, Simic Guildgate and Thornwood Falls definitely aren't the same. The former is a gate, and the latter gains you life.)

Comment: @Jefromi Firstly thank you for answering my question! But I'm confused, the oracle text specifies that both of them, when tapped, add either a land or forest mana to my pool?

Comment: They both add blue or green mana (not "island" or "forest" mana - there is no such thing), yes. That one ability is the same. But the overall card is certainly not the same - the oracle text for both includes more than just that ability. It doesn't matter for your question (different name is all that matters for decks) but they're absolutely not identical cards even if you ignore the name.

Comment: @Jefromi oh geez I'm sorry, I don't know how I missed that. And yeah I guess I have a bad habit of calling them forest not green. Thank you for clearing up any confusion!

Comment: there are exceptions when you can run multiple cards in one deck, for example Shadowborn Apostle